# Group Perl object by child nodes

Tags: perl, sorting, object

I have an object in the format shown below, and I need to group them by available months. The 1000, 2000, ect. are amounts in dollars, and the next level are (6, 4) are months.

My Object:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1000' => {
                      '6' => {
                               'APR' => '13.9'
                             },
                      '4' => {
                               'APR' => '11.9'
                             }
                    },
          '2000' => {
                      '6' => {
                               'APR' => '13.9'
                             },
                      '4' => {
                               'APR' => '11.9'
                             }
                    },
          '4000' => {
                      '6' => {
                               'APR' => '13.9'
                             },
                      '4' => {
                               'APR' => '11.9'
                             }
                    }
          '5000' => {
                      '6' => {
                               'APR' => '13.9'
                             }
                    }
        };
```

The Object I Want:

```
$VAR1 = {
    '6' => {
             '1000',
             '2000',
             '4000',
             '5000'
           },
    '4' => {
             '1000',
             '2000',
             '4000'
           }
}
```

Comment: An object is something you can call methods on. What you want is simply a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my %new_hash;
for my $amount (sort { $a <=> $b } keys(%$VAR1)) {
   for my $month (keys(%{ $VAR1->{$amount} })) {
      push @{ $new_hash{$month} }, $amount;
   }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a more elegant solution, thank you very much!

Comment: My one suggestion is to not sort, as it adds nothing to a hash, since a hash will put it wherever it wants. Sorting after the fact would be more efficient. This is `nlogn+n` with the sort; however, thanks for the simple code!

Comment: @Patrick Robert Shea O'Connor, I'm sorting the contents of an array, not a hash. And it's merely `O(N log N)` (rather than `O(N)`) with the sort. There's no `+ N` (and even if there was, it would simplify away)